# Application option vanished from menu

Tags: raspbian, pi-3b+, raspbian-buster, raspberry-pi-os

I just installed kali linux tools and menu with katoolin , the i went to check that tools got install or not in applications , but there was no applications option that just vanished ! All the existing applications moved into "Usual Applications ". The I tried to get applications option back by going into preferences then to edit main menu . But it shows that there is Application option in "edit main menu" with all kali linux tools in it.. , help me get this fixed .

Comment: [Kali](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5360/why-is-kali-linux-so-hard-to-set-up-why-wont-people-help-me)

Comment: Bad idea so far!

Answer (score 1):

If you are using katoolin then you must maintain the installed applications carefully. If any packages conflict from different repo your system might never work. And in this case you have replaced a portion of your system files with kali tools!!
You have two options. Remove all applications from kali tools
Or reinstall the system.
(Suggestion: If you want to use kali them simply install kali from re4son)